# Can I restrict :s to a particular substring of a line?

Tags: regular-expression, substitute, ex-mode, filetype-markdown

I ran into this doing a quick conversion of markdown into JIRA markdown.

```
- A standard markdown list
  - hierarchical
  - easy to read
    - tidy

- A JIRA markdown list
-- Hierarchical
-- Somewhat more annoying to read
--- Why, JIRA, why?
```

Expressed in English, what I needed to do was:

On any line beginning with spaces followed by a hyphen followed by at least one space, replace `"^  "` (two leading spaces) with `"-"` repeatedly
    for all instances of two spaces up to the hyphen.

What I actually did, which comes close, was:

```
:g/^\s\+- /s/  /-/g
```

But, if there are any instances of two consecutive spaces elsewhere in the line (after the first hyphen), this will incorrectly convert them to a hyphen.

Is there any way to make `:s` match not globally, but only on some specified part of the line?  Perhaps on a backreference?

**Imaginary syntax** for applying a substitute command globally, but only to the part of the line captured in a backreference:

```
:g/g/^\s\+- / /^\(\s\+\)/ \1s/  /-/g
```

Answer (score 2):

In this specific case, you want to replace leading matches of  with an equal number of `-`:

```
:g/^\s\+- /s:^\(  \)*:\=repeat('-', strlen(submatch(0))/2):g
```

Source:

- [Vim regex replace with n characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7338794/2072269)

More generally, you can use expressions (in particular, the [`subtitute()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#substitute%28%29) function) in the replacement in combination with `\zs`/`\ze` (or lookaheads and lookbehinds) (as seen in the example in [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/5081/205)), to act *only* on a section of the line:

```
s:^\(  \)*:\=substitute(submatch(0), '  ', '-', 'g'):g
```

Here, the section is well-anchored already, and there was no need for `\zs` or lookarounds.